# Application Continuity on Single instance

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, rac

I recently was going through Application Continuity in Oracle 12c. As I read through the [Oracle link](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/appcontnew.htm#JJDBC29081) which I understand when used in RAC, will be able to replay the transaction (DDL/DML) in the event the node goes down.

In the link, it also mentions creating a service for non-RAC (standalone) instances as well. How does Application continuity work in case of single instance.

```
declare
params dbms_service.svc_parameter_array;
begin
params('FAILOVER_TYPE'):='TRANSACTION';
params('REPLAY_INITIATION_TIMEOUT'):=1800;
params('RETENTION_TIMEOUT'):=604800;
params('FAILOVER_DELAY'):=10;
params('FAILOVER_RETRIES'):=30;
params('commit_outcome'):='true';
params('aq_ha_notifications'):='true';
dbms_service.modify_service('[your service]',params);
end;
/
```

Say, if a recoverable error occurs on the single instance, where does it replay the transaction? Can someone help me understand this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application Continuity is not limited to RAC. It works with Data Guard as well. For example an in-flight transaction can be replayed after a switchover on the new primary (former standby). With a single instance primary and standby, this requires the Active Data Guard option to be licensed.

[Application Continuity](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SBYDB/concepts.htm#SBYDB5461)

> Application Continuity is supported for Oracle Data Guard switchovers
>   to physical standby databases. It is also supported for fast-start
>   failover to physical standbys in maximum availability data protection
>   mode. Note that primary and standby databases must be licensed for
>   Oracle RAC **or Oracle Active Data Guard** in order to use Application
>   Continuity.

Comment: @Balaza Papp thanks again, can you also clarify some of my queries in my previous question as well?